# How to Convert Python Script to a Python Application?

Tags: python, docker, web-applications, package

I have a Python program that asks the user to **"Enter Link"** and then download all files from that link. But all of this happens on the terminal after manually compiling the program like

```
python myapp.py
```

I'm using libraries like **BeautifulSoup/urlparse** and if run on another computer, I'll have to install libraries again. Is there an alternative way to convert the script into an app in a way that the user does not have to manually install all libraries first?

I have already tried the **Packaging Python Projects**
but this command never works for me

```
dist/
  example_pkg_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
  example_pkg_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

and hence I get stuck.

Comment: Try converting your .py file into executable format. You can refer this link: https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi

Answer (score 0):

There are mulitple solutions for your problem. One would be using a library like [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [Py2Exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/). Although they can be a little tricky in configuration matters. Especially with a lot of packages. But I think, it is the most suitable solution for end-users.

Another way would be distributing your whole Python environment with your script. If small file size is required, there are also embeddable Python environments.

You could also distribute a Batch-File, which then installs your dependencies.